# GAS セルの画像を取得し、別のセルに貼りつけることはできますか？

Tags: google-apps-script

例：シート1のセルの値とシート2のセルの値を比較して同じ場合、そのセルにある画像を取得し、シート1のセルに貼り付けることは可能でしょうか。